# What are PyQGIS Functions for MakeFeatureLayer and SelectLayerByLocation?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a script that I had created using ModelBuilder, but our field personnel use QGIS 2.0.  Below is a snippet of the code. I am wanting to know if there is an equivalent using pyqgis so that I can add it to my plugin.

```
# Process: Make Asset Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(asset_wps, Asset_Selection, "\"ASSET_TYPE\" = 'Secondary Ped' OR \"ASSET_TYPE\" = 'XFMR'")

# Process: Make PC Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Proposed_Conductor, PC_Selection, "\"CONDUCTOR_\" = 'Underground Secondary' OR \"CONDUCTOR_\" = 'Underground Service'")

# Process: Select Layer By Location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Asset_Selection, "INTERSECT", PC_Selection, "1.5", "NEW_SELECTION")

matchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(Output).getOutput(0)) 
print('E1012: {0}').format(matchcount)
```

So what I am doing here is just making a selection from two features and then checking where they intersect with that selection and finally getting a count.

How can I replace MakeFeatureLayer and SelectLayerByLocation using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a way to do what you want :

```
## define datasource
asset_wps = QgsVectorLayer("path/your/asset/datasource", 'Assets', 'ogr')
proposed_conductor = QgsVectorLayer("path/your/conductor/datasource", 'Proposed Conductor', 'ogr')
## your "where" clauses
where_clause1 = "ASSET_TYPE = 'Secondary Ped' OR ASSET_TYPE = 'XFMR'"
where_clause2 = "CONDUCTOR_ = 'Underground Secondary' OR CONDUCTOR_ = 'Underground Service'"

matchcount = 0
for f1 in asset_wps.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(where_clause1)):
    for f2 in proposed_conductor.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(where_clause2)):
        ## here get if feature 1 intersects with feature 2
        if f1.geometry().intersects(f2.geometry()):
            matchcount += 1

print('E1012: {0}').format(matchcount)
```

you can also use `setSubsetString` directly on `QgsVectorLayer` instead of `QgsFeatureRequest` (in this case I'll use `double QgsGeometry::distance(QgsGeometry &geom)` instead of the `intersects` function):

```
asset_wps.setSubsetString("ASSET_TYPE = 'Secondary Ped' OR ASSET_TYPE = 'XFMR'")
proposed_conductor.setSubsetString("CONDUCTOR_ = 'Underground Secondary' OR CONDUCTOR_ = 'Underground Service'")

matchcount = 0
for f1 in asset_wps.getFeatures():
    for f2 in proposed_conductor.getFeatures():
        if f1.geometry().distance(f2.geometry()) <= 1.5:
            matchcount += 1

print('E1012: {0}').format(matchcount)
```

Comment: I went with the later suggestion and it worked great. One thing I did add though, was to set the SubsetString back to '' at the end of the code. I found out with my plugin, that the query was applied to my layers I had in the drawing and stayed that way until it was cleared out.

Asset.setSubsetString('')
ProposedConductor.setSubsetString('')

Answer (score 0):

For making in-memory features check out:

[Memory Provider](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider)

For select layer by location check out Sextante selection methods:

[QGIS-SEXTANTE cookbook](http://qgissextante.blogspot.in/2013/01/using-selection-algorithms.html)